# Markers not showing until map moved slightly or clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

my (cut down) code is as below.  My markers are not showing up until I either click or move the map slightly... is there any way of getting around this so they show up instantly?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>TSF - Labour Plan </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.644638, -2.526855);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: centerlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.752927, -0.470095);
    var img = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55888592/tsf-logo.gif";
    var info = "<img style = 'float: left' src='http://www.tsf.uk.com/wp-content/themes/default/images/tsf-logo.gif'><div style = 'float: right; width: 200px'><p><b>Job Number:</b> </p><p><b>Client:</b> ASDA</p><p><b>Location:</b> HEMEL HEMPSTEAD</p><p><b>Postcode:</b> HP2 4AA</p><p><b>Start Time:</b> 22:0</p><p><b>No of Men:</b> 10.0</p><p><b>Allocated Labour:</b> AB: 5.0, WK: 5.0, : , : , : , : </p><p><b>Job Information: </b>PICK UP TOOLS</div>";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: img,
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    content: info
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(content) {
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are calling `initialize` twice, once with a `DomListener` and once with `body onload`. I would remove the `body onload` call. See if that helps. I would also move your javascript out of the head and into the body. Locally, I'm not having any issues.

Comment: I tried that but had no luck. I've just checked it in explorer and it works fine so this issue seems to be with chrome? the only similar issue I could find online was this:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/jLsVUoF9-Zk

Comment: I had no issues in Chrome on Mac. Maybe due to a missing DOCTYPE? Add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at the top of the file.

Comment: How did you simplify the code?  Do you see the issue with this version?  Are you using a MarkerClusterer or MarkerManager (in the version that isn't cutdown)?

Comment: My full code just has more markers, yeah I'm having an issue with this version.  No, i'm not using markerclusterer or markermanager.

Comment: Most likely a problem with your development environment or test environment then as I don't see it on a local copy of the posted code (only tested in Chrome), and neither does brouxhaha.

Comment: I am facing the same issue however my situation is a bit different. i have hardly 6 markers....The markers which are SVG objects are not visible unless map is moved....the ones which are png icons are visible instantly....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that the problem is still exists in google chrome in most recent version on google map api and marker cluster js.

So I'll post the code which helped in this issue for me.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var cnt = map.getCenter();
        cnt.e+=0.000001;
        map.panTo(cnt);
        cnt.e-=0.000001;
        map.panTo(cnt);
    },400);
});
```

feel free to play with value of interval of 400 (in my case less than 400 woudn't fix problem, but higher value - higher lag time)

P.S.
make sure you have defined map variable:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. You seen a buglist post on Google for this?

Comment: I experienced the same problem using 100+ markers.  Some markers were missing on PC browser but on mobile devices vastly more.  I found simulating any user action on the map that caused it to move fixed it.  Essentially the same as your code.

Comment: Op needs to change his answer to this one... the setTimeout and slight panTo and back is definitely the answer. Dropped it into my code where I was experience this issue, and it was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with the EXACTLY same problem and was so glad to hear other guys have the same problem. I experienced the problem with GMaps V3 in Safari and Firefox as well. I tried your solution and it works for me as well but I used the idle event instead the timeout:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(event) {
    var cnt = map.getCenter();
    cnt.e+=0.000001;
    map.panTo(cnt);
    cnt.e-=0.000001;
    map.panTo(cnt);
});
```

Just add it on initializing Google Maps. There might come up another issue working with infowindows and circles bound to markers. In my case I can set the radius of the circle in the infobox. Jumping out of the input field (with or without changing the radius value) makes red-like markers blue. If you then zoom in/out the original color reappears. To solve this problem you have to change the zoom level quickly (in radius_changed event):

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this calling repaint on markerclusterer variable twice:

```
mc.repaint();
map.fitBounds(bounds); // for centering within the marker bounds
mc.repaint(); // repaint for getting it fixed
```

Hope this helps to anyone still facing the issue.

Comment: This is simple and it works for me. I will have to keep my eyes on the map for any side-effect though :D

Answer (score 1):

As per Geocodezips comment, this seems to be a local issue.

Comment: "local issue" might happen anywhere.. how did you get rid of the problem and what could be the cause?

Comment: I didn't, but it doesn't happen in IE which is where I will be using it mostly... and if it's not happening in other peoples Chrome it must be a problem on my side.